# Allow URI schemes for chrome extension manifest matches

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, uri

I am making a chrome extension, however, I have come across the problem that my content script will not run on a `chrome-extension://*` scheme. I've found this is because it is a URI scheme rather than a URL. Is it possible to allow in my `manifest.json` to add URI schemes to the matches array?

Otherwise if it is not possible, is there any other way to open this html under a file path?

**manifest.json**

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "description": "Description",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**edit**
I found this site (`https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/permissions/permissions_data_unittest.cc`) where on lines `377 to 393` talks about "Regular" and "Component" extensions and how "Component" extensions should have access to `chrome-extension://` schemes when `<all_urls>` are specified. Im not sure what this source code is but if there is any information on that, then that is the point I am at in researching currently.

Answer (score 0):

The approach on the https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/permissions/permissions_data_unittest.cc code in line 377 could be feasible for you (also if you figured it out already please post the solution you implemented). However, if you follow the above mentioned approach you will be still working with URLs. Maybe if you explain how do you pretend to access the URIs from the background script and how the URIs are formed (maybe they have a commond pattern) it will be clearer. If you need to use specific resources that will be located within the URLs of your scope, implementing "matches": ["https://yourpage1.com/*, https://yourpage2.com/* <>"], should do the trick without being concerned about CORS or SOP, even for the URI long version (eg:mydomain.yourpage1.com/resource1.png, mydomain.yourpage1.com/resource1.index.html, etc.).